# PHP 5.4.6 or 5.3.16 for production?

Tags: php5

On php.net, we can read :  All users of PHP are encouraged to upgrade to PHP 5.4.6, or **at least** 5.3.16.
Does it mean that it is better to use 5.4.6 than 5.3.16, even for production ?
I have heard that 5.4.6 is not stable.

I would be interested in 5.4.6 in order to use http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php, but will not if PHP 5.4.6 is not stable.

Thank you.

Comment: "I have heard"? From whom? Test your application in both. If it works in both, I'd use the more recent version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For developing a new project from scratch, I would go with 5.4. It will have a much longer shelf life than 5.3 or prior versions.

For deploying an existing project, including any open source PHP code you downloaded from the Internet, I would use PHP 5.3. The reason for this is that 5.4 has [a few places where backward compatibility was broken](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php), and some existing PHP scripts will need updating to be compatible with 5.4. In a few cases, the package would have to be completely refactored to work with 5.4.

See the [PHP 5.4 migration guide](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php) for all the gory details.

Answer (score 4):

5.4 series has some important features not available in 5.3. I have not seen anything in 5.4 that is not stable. Keep in mind that sometimes, people quote "unstable" loosely based on their experience without proper testing. A good number of issues I have seen in PHP are not related to PHP itself.

I always compile PHP from source and include only the extensions I need. It keeps it clean and less bloat.

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5.4.6 and PHP 5.3.16 are stable releases with the difference that PHP 5.3.16 has been longer in the field and 5.4 is fairly recent.

Either one you choose, ensure your application is well tested..

Choose 5.4 since it will have longer life, is stable, has the features you need and has had 6 bug fix releases already.